# Concat, or merge two dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes here with shape of first dataframes are (10840, 109) and the second are (0,112)

I want to concat/merge two dataframes above. I tried `df_part_2 = pd.concat([df_revisi_data,df_migrasi_part2],axis=1)`, however the result was (10840, 221). I tried another way with `df_part_2 = pd.concat([df_revisi_data,df_migrasi_part2],axis=0)` but error rise `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Honestly, all columns on the first dataframe are exist on the second dataframes. However, the result don't meet my expectation. The result of the new dataframe shape are (10840,112) with the data contain of the first dataframe, but the columns referes to the second dataframe.

slice of first dataframe

```
    No  Lead ID*      Nama Petani   Point   Tanggal Pengajuan*  Nama PIC Utama* Email PIC Utama*    Grading Point*  CF0 FUA pov - Status*   CF0 FUA pov - Start Date*   ... CF10 Verifikasi PKS - Email PIC*    CF10 Open Limit - Status*   CF10 Open Limit - Start Date*   CF10 Open Limit - End Date* CF10 Open Limit - Remarks   CF10 Open Limit - Nama PIC* CF10 Open Limit - Email PIC*    Review \nby Eng Migrated \nby Eng   Note \nby Eng
0   1   5147hvhaau26    AMAN WIJAYA LOMBOK TENGAH   2021-08-01 00:00:00 Ria Arumsari    ria.arumsari@efishery.com   Grade B APPROVED    2021-08-01 00:00:00 ... fitria.rahma@efishery.com   ACTIVE  2021-10-16 00:00:00 2021-10-16 00:00:00 STATUS DETAIL: REMARKS: Fitria Rahma Nur S  fitria.rahma@efishery.com   TRUE    TRUE    None
1   2   512bcr75iqp8    SAHMA DAHNIARTI BENGKULU SELATAN    2021-08-01 00:00:00 Fitria Rahma Nur S  fitria.rahma@efishery.com   Grade A APPROVED    2021-08-01 00:00:00 ... fitria.rahma@efishery.com   ACTIVE  2021-08-27 00:00:00 2021-08-27 00:00:00 STATUS DETAIL: Next Step - Open Access REMARKS: Fitria Rahma Nur S  fitria.rahma@efishery.com   TRUE    TRUE    None
2   3   5124qwzj2vxv    CAHYO SUBEKTI   SLEMAN  2021-08-02 00:00:00 Fitria Rahma Nur S  fitria.rahma@efishery.com   Grade B APPROVED
```

slice of second dataframe (actually only header of columns)

```
No  Kode Nominatif  Lead ID*    Nama Petani Point   Tanggal Pengajuan*  Nama PIC Utama* Email PIC Utama*    Requested Amount    Grading Point*
```

the result I expected:

```
    No  Kode Nominatif  Lead ID*    Nama Petani Point   Tanggal Pengajuan*  Nama PIC Utama* Email PIC Utama*    Requested Amount    Grading Point*
    1    nan           5147hvhaau26 AMAN WIJAYA LOMBOK TENGAH   2021-08-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: please provide minimal example to reproduce.

Comment: (0,112) means 0 rows and 112 cols? Weird df

Comment: @srinath pleas kindly check my edited question

Comment: @ArrowRise yes 0 row and 112 cols. actually I just want to add some new columns on the current dataframe, however, I want to concat two another another dataframe in order the order of columns on current dataframe should be same the the order of the second dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if this sample helps

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : [1,2,3,4,5],
    'col2' : [6,7,8,9,10],
    'col3': [11,12,13,14,15],
    'col4': [16,17,18,19,20]
    
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col3", "col4", "col5"])
```

Concat using

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

Result

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   1.0 6.0 11  16  NaN
1   2.0 7.0 12  17  NaN
2   3.0 8.0 13  18  NaN
3   4.0 9.0 14  19  NaN
4   5.0 10.0    15  20  NaN
```

IIUC, your first df has values and the second df is empty. second df has extra columns where you want nan. Lemme know if my understanding is erroneous.